# Permalink problems with custom post type and custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, custom-post-type-archives

### Question 1 Permalink structure

I trying to implement the right url/permalink structure for my site, but I can't get it to work.

I have the following setup:

**Custom post type: training**

```
  register_post_type( 'training',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Trainingen' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Training' ),
            'all_items'           => __( 'Alle trainingen' ),
            'view_item'           => __( 'Bekijk training' ),
            'add_new_item'        => __( 'Nieuwe training' ),
            'add_new'             => __( 'Nieuwe training' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'our-training', 'with_front' => false),
        'show_in_rest' => true
        )
    );
```

```
**Custom taxonomy : training-category**
```

```
    $args = array(
        "label" => ( "training category"),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "rewrite" => array( 'slug' => 'training-category', 'with_front' => true, ),
        "show_admin_column" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "has_archive" => true,
        "show_ui" => true
        );
    register_taxonomy( "training_category", array( "event", "post", "training", "employee"), $args );
```

The permalink structure I want to establish:

```
our-training/training-category-1/training-name-1
our-training/training-category-2/training-name-2
our-training/training-category-1/training-name-3
```

what I do get is:

```
our-training/training-name-1
our-training/training-name-2
our-training/training-name-3
```

So the custom taxonomy is not inserted correctly in the permalink.

*(I am also using Yoast breadcrumbs and have set the taxonomy to show for the training cpt to:  training-category (my custom tax).)*

Any tips on how I can get the desired permalink structure?

### ***Question 2 - Redirect***

Secondly I use facetwp for filtering so I need to redirect the category archive to a facetwp archive page.
Redirect I want to establish (simplyfied):

our-training/training-category-1

must redirect to:

our-training?cat=training-category-1

How can I do this the best way?

Any pointers in the right direction will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Set the `with_front` key to TRUE in your CPT arguments. That should help with question 1

Comment: Thanks a lot Nathan, that seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem with archive page and pagination in the original answer. Therefore, instead of changing the `"rewrite" => ['slug' => 'our-training/%training-category%']` in `register_post_type()`
as I suggested earlier, add the following rewrite rules and change the links created for CPT.

The rules will handle such addresses:

- display single `training` post with pagination support

```
/our-training/training-category-1/training-name/
/our-training/training-category-1/training-name/2/
```

- display `training` posts assigned to `training-category-1` (uncomment first rewrite rule)
  **note:** *this is query for taxonomy term, not cpt, so the [first available template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) from the list will be used: `taxonomy-training_category.php` > `taxonomy.php` > `archive.php`*

```
/our-training/training-category-1/
/our-training/training-category-1/page/2/
```

Default rules will handle:

- display all `training` posts (archive)

```
/our-training/
```

- display all posts (any type, "event", "employee", etc.) assigned to `training-category-1`

```
/training-category/training-category-1/
```

This code worked for me.

```
add_action( 'init', 'se391612_cpt_permalink', 20 );
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'se391612_term_in_cpt_link', 20, 4 );

function se391612_cpt_permalink()
{
    //
    // CPT posts from custom taxonomy term (term archive)
    //add_rewrite_rule(
    //    'our-training/([^/]+)(?:/page/?([0-9]+))?/?$', 
    //    'index.php?post_type=training&training_category=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
    //    'top'
    //);    
    //
    // single post with pagination 
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'our-training/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$', 
        'index.php?post_type=training&training=$matches[2]&page=$matches[3]',
        'top'
    );
}

function se391612_term_in_cpt_link( $post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample )
{
    if ( ! $post instanceof \WP_Post || 'training' != $post->post_type)
        return $post_link;
    $new_link = $post_link;
    $all_terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'training_category', [
        'hide_empty' => '0',
        'fields' => 'slugs',
        'orderby' => 'term_id',
    ] );
    if ( !is_array($all_terms) || 0 == count($all_terms) )
        return $post_link;

    $term = array_shift($all_terms) . '/';
    $new_link = str_replace('our-training/', 'our-training/'.$term, $new_link);

    return $new_link;
}
```

**Important note:**
If you uncomment the first `add_rewrite_rule()` to support `/our-training/training-category-1` permalink format,
an address collision will occur. For WP there is no difference between these addresses,
how it interprets them depends on the order of rewrite rules.

```
/our-training/training-category-1   // all "training" post from category "training-category-1"
/our-training/some-training-name    // single "training" post
```

However, if you would like both address types to work
and you know that **there will be only several categories**, you can add
these categories in the rules (manually or automatically).

---

**Reference**:
[`register_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#parameters)
[`wp_get_post_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/)
[`post_type_link` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_type_link/)

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for this answer. This is helping a lot, and it works for our-training/training-category-1/training-name-3 and our-training/training-category-1/ but I get a 404 on our-training/ even though there is an archive-training.php which I don't understand.

Comment: Oh I actually got this to work with another rewrite rule:
`$new['training/?$'] = 'index.php?xpost_type=training';`

All permalinks seem to be working fine now, I'll be having a go at sorting the breadcrumbs out now. Thanks for your input!